# Why does my result from *args begin with an empty list in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning Python and have never used the arbitrary-number argument functions before, and I'm having trouble understanding why I'm getting what I'm getting. Specifically, I'm running this code:

```
class LocationList(list):
    def __init__(*pargs):
        print(pargs)
        print(len(pargs))
        for the_item in pargs:
            print(the_item)

the_location = LocationList('a location', 'another location')
```

And what I'm getting is this:

```
([], 'a location', 'another location')
3
[]
a location
another location
```

Why am I getting the empty list at the beginning?

I'm using Python 3.4.3 under Linux.

Comment: It's the `self` parameter. It's displayed as a list because you inherit from list, inheriting its `__str__` and `__repr__` methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the first argument to a method is the object it is called on. And the object is a descendant of `list`. And an empty list prints as "[]".

Answer (score 2):

Methods within a class has self as the first argument, including

```
__init__()
```

To get the result I think you were looking for:

```
def __init__(self, *pargs):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

*pargs, since it is prefixed with '*' (an asterisk), collects all of the arguments into a tuple. Also, for class and object method definitions, the first argument is always "self", which is, in this case the object (or instance) that you create when you do this:

```
the_location = LocationList('a location', 'another location')
```

Further, your class is extending list:

```
class LocationList(list):
```

Therefore, self (the object) becomes a list:

```
([], 'a location', 'another location') # self == []
```